# Creating dynamic class this pointer

Tags: php

I am noob in PHP because I am mostly do .NET/Java. In code base I am working, I have,

```
class SomeOtherBaseClass{
  public $prop2;
public function __construct(string $prop3)
{
    $this->prop2 = $prop3;
}
 public function __toString()
   {
     return $this->prop2 . ' '. $this->prop2;
   }
}
class SomeClass 
{
 public function __toString()
   {
     return $this->prop1 . ' '. $this->prop1;
   }
    public $prop1;

    public function someMethod() : SomeOtherBaseClass
    {
        return $this->createClass();
    }

    public function __construct()
{
    $this->prop1 = 'foo';
}

    private function createClass(
    ): SomeOtherBaseClass {
        return new class(
            $this->prop1
        ) extends SomeOtherBaseClass {


        };
    }
}
$class = new SomeClass();
echo $class;
echo $class->someMethod();
```

Why I am getting error that prop1 not found. Clearly `createClass` function is part of `SomeClass` which have `prop1`. Why I cannot access `prop1` inside `createClass`?

Comment: If you install Composer (its like maven), then you can `composer require nette/php-generator`, which is awesome for generating classes https://github.com/nette/php-generator. The syntax for what you are doing is competely wrong btw.

Comment: code edited and its working https://repl.it/repls/SinfulWrySequence. I think the issue is with PhpStorm editor not with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `$prop1` has no value or meaning.

You can add a __construct() function to resolve your issue:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->prop1 = 'foo';
}
```

now when you call this class (e.g. `$foo = new SomeClass();`):

`$prop1` has a value of `foo` which can be used in your functions:

```
public function echoProp()
{
    echo $this->prop1; # will output foo
}
```

Note: This is just an explanation answer - not a copy/paste solution - but the principles are all here for you to use in your code.

Let me know if this wasn't what you were looking for :)

Edit:

if `prop1` exists in `SomeOtherClass`, when you construct you can do

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->class = new SomeClass();
    $this->prop1 = $this->class->prop1;
}
```

Comment: issue was with PhpStrom. Here is working one https://repl.it/repls/SinfulWrySequence